# render empty cells as anchor in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am working on a project where users create appointments using fullcalendar. Users can only create appointments on those timeslots(30min) that are available. These events are coming from a file named as events_json.php. All the other timeslots that don't have any event should render an anchor saying "Book me".

i am using the agendaweek as default calendar view. upon inspection i can only see rows and no columns(like this)

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr data-time="00:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>12am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="00:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="01:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>1am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="01:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="02:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>2am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="02:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="03:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>3am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="03:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="04:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>4am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="04:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="05:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>5am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="05:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="06:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>6am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="06:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="07:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>7am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="07:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="08:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>8am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="08:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="09:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>9am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="09:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="10:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>10am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="10:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="11:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>11am</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="11:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="12:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>12pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="12:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="13:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>1pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="13:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="14:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>2pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="14:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="15:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>3pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="15:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="16:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>4pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="16:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="17:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>5pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="17:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="18:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>6pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="18:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="19:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>7pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="19:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="20:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>8pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="20:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="21:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>9pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="21:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="22:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>10pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="22:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="23:00:00">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"><span>11pm</span></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-time="23:30:00" class="fc-minor">
         <td class="fc-axis fc-time ui-widget-content" style="width: 55.5781px;"></td>
         <td class="ui-widget-content"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How do i achieve this functionality where every empty box should be a clickable anchor saying "Book me".

i have done some research on this thing and found a similar question where this code was written but it was not for me.

```
viewRender: function(view, $element) {
                $element.find('.fc-day-number').each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var match = (/^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)$/).exec($this.attr('data-date'));
                    var date = new Date(+match[1], +match[2], +match[3]);

                    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="http://www.example.com/booking.php?booking_date=' + encodeURIComponent(date.toUTCString()) + '" target="_blank"></a>');
                });
            },
```

Comment: you've asked about this on a separate question I answered for you. Again I'd question why you need to do this? If you provide a simple instruction to the user to click on an empty slot in order to book it, they will soon get the idea. And then when you handle the "select" event, you can see what time they have selected, and you can use javascript to redirect them to the booking page. I think you will save yourself a lot of time and effort by dropping the requirement for a hyperlink.

Comment: The problem is, i know i can instruct the user but this is a requirement. in other words this needs to be done. i am working on it and i know that you have answered my previous question for which i am very grateful to you. This also needs to be done.

Comment: Requirements are not set in stone. They can be changed if you convince the right people that it will cost too much and there is an easier/better solution. I can't see a way to achieve what you want without altering the fullCalendar source code, or building your own View (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/). Neither of those options is simple, and as I said there's a straightforward way of providing the same functionality, without cluttering up the screen with hyperlinks. But if your employer wants you to spend weeks working on a custom view, then that's their problem!

Comment: As a matter of fact i came here after burning up those resources, there are further things also that the client has asked

Comment: 1) events coming from the server should be displayed as "Taken" (achieved)..
2) A hyperlink saying "Book Me" on all the non-taken fields(work inprogress)
3) There should be no holidays appearing and view should starting from MON upto the next MON(6 working days)

Comment: the customer is not always right! And they don't always know what is technically possible and what is not. So part of your job is to advise them on the best solution. Their real objective is not to place a hyperlink on the page (even though maybe they expressed it like that). Their real objective is to allow people to book appointments. So you can suggest to them a better, cheaper way to do it. They will like it if it's cheaper and quicker :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122806/discussion-between-umair-ashfr-and-adyson).